# Single Line Out in C#

Tags: c#

This is the kind of question that usually gets closed because it's not "constructive". But I hope it will not this time. I was thinking of sending a feedback to the C# team about the fact that this block:

```
int i;
string str;
object obj;
AnyOutMethod(out i, out str, out obj);
```

is ugly compared to the new style I'm suggesting which is:

```
AnyOutMethod(out int i, out string str, out object obj);
```

Does my approach have any negative aspect? Doesn't it make sense to have this syntax supported in a future version of C#?

Comment: What would be the scope of str and obj? The place until the next closing bracket? Or the whole enclosing method? Either way I wouldn't support this idea. Just would make things more complicated, because you might overlook a field declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like [declaration expressions](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/09/15/c-6-0-features-part-3-declaration-expressions.aspx), which were proposed for C# 6.0 but did not make the cut. The [cited reason](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/568820) was that they were...

> characterized by having large amounts of downstream work still
>   remaining. They are also features that we see as the potential
>   beginning of a bigger story further down the line: ... declaration expressions would form the corner stone of pattern
>   matching and deconstruction facilities. Now, those features will all
>   be considered together for a later release.

Current work related to that feature area, as the quote suggests, seems to be tagged with the ["pattern matching"](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues?q=declaration%20expression%20label%3A%22New%20Language%20Feature%20-%20Pattern%20Matching%22) tag on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn). [This issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/6183) specifically seems to map to a modern version of what you are proposing.

Naturally there are negatives and subtle issues to consider when adding new syntax to the language; the general sense seems to be in favor of the feature at the broad level, but that there is concern over sorting out the implementation details, mainly

- scope of the declared variable
- mutability (or not) of the variable
- issues surrounding whether or not the variable is definitely assigned (see examples related to `foo is SomeType bar`)
- how the feature plays with broader pattern-matching features in discussion

based on a cursory read-through of the issue.